# Android Studio Navigation Drawer fragments overlapping

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've added a Navigation drawer activity to my project and I'm trying to add items as fragments. This is what I have done in the main activity.

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
           public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
            {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.nav_home)
                {
                    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new HomeFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }
                else if(id == R.id.Shopping_list)
                {
                    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new ShoppingListFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
                else if(id == R.id.nav_Language)
                {
                    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new FragmentLang());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
```

The default fragment is Home which is working fine and as expected BUT the other fragments are overlapping with the Home Fragment. (The HomeFragment is the only one that's working fine).
I've done something like this inside every Fragment class:

```
public class ShoppingListFragment extends Fragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_list, container,false);
   return view;
    }

}
```

I can't see where the mistake is. everything looks good but all other fragments are showing over the HomeFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fragment manager maintains the stack of all the previous fragments that are replaced sometimes the back stack fragments overlap with the fragment we replaced, add this line

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

like this,

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new HomeFragment());
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Hope will help. Happy coding :)